# Loading Preferences From Another Source

Tags: android

I would like to load and store Preferences from another source but the Android Shared Preferences XML file. I know that it is possible to track changes in my Preference Activity by registering an **OnPreferenceChangeListener** but how do I load the preferences from my own storage.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by mine own storage?

You can specify the file name for Shared Preferences to be used. There are also other options for saving state information.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: i.e. I would like to load and store the preferences from/to an own SQLite DB.

Comment: Then simply do not use Shared Preferences. Instead add appropriate code in onResume or onStart methods to query database.

Comment: Well this means I have to find all Preference Panes and then manually loading its value, even though Android has such a handy Preference Framework? Sounds useless complicated.